# csrf token in react router

Tags: spring, forms, security, reactjs

I am using react and spring security and want to pass csrf token when user click on logout button. Any suggestion how to include csrf token in react. I have searched for the solution on google but not getting any solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexLink, Link } from 'react-router';

const Nav = (props) => (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="navbar-header">
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">GoRFQ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ><Link onlyActiveOnIndex activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li ><Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/boms'>BOMs</Link></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Quotes</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/quotesin' >Incoming Quotes</Link>
              <Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/quotesout' >Outgoing Quotes</Link>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Requests</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/requestsin' >Received Requests</Link>
              <Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/requestsout' >Sent Requests</Link>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li ><Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/upload'>Upload BOM</Link></li>
          <li ><Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/contacts'>Contacts</Link></li>
          <li ><Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/profile'>My Profile</Link></li>
          <li ><Link activeStyle={{color:'#052426'}} to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <form action="/perform-logout" method="post" className="pull-right">
             <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Out"/>

          </form>


        </div>
      </nav>
);

export default Nav;
```

Comment: <input type="hidden"
 name={csrf}
 value={token}/>

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. getting this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: csrf is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to share the answer that how I made it work, so it will help someone else. I did following things:

1) I installed react-cookie.

2) In my react component I imported this react-cookie

import Cookie from 'react-cookie';

3) Extracted the XSRF-TOKEN from cookie and passed as hidden field in form

```
<form action="/perform-logout" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={Cookie.load('XSRF-TOKEN')}/>
                   <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign Out"/>
                </form>
```

And it worked.

Comment: doesn't that defeats the purpose of csrf token all together ?

Comment: @aeid not really. A malicious web page can't read the XSRF-TOKEN cookie attached to the target domain with Javascript and therefore can't send it in the form field. The browser will still send the authentication cookie + XSRF-TOKEN cookie to the target application, but the attacker can't access the XSRF value 
 from the other domain. (there are some nuances to this)

Comment: I try with the latest version react-cookie@3.0.0 not working but it working fine with old version react-cookie@1.0.5. Do you know why?

Comment: Using secure, httponly, samesite cookies is the preferred method to do this. Headers and public endpoints would allow an attacker to read the CSRF token.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the follow config in the spring security

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository().withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                        .getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
```

The csrfHeaderFilter will add the csrf token to the response in XSRF-TOKEN and send to the client's cookies. the next time client read XSRF-TOKEN token in the cookies and put it in http request header in with key X-XSRF-TOKEN, spring will use the CsrfTokenRepository to find X-XSRF-TOKEN in client header  .

the withHttpOnlyFalse() method set the httpOnly to false, it mean that the js  client can read the csrf token in the client's cookies, if not, the js client can not read it,may be the default is withHttpOnlyFalse().

You can look at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/.It sumit the csrftoken with a angular client. But i think it almost the same if you use the react client. Hope can help you.

Comment: I have added above config in my security config but now getting this exception


Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.and() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: It could spring-security version problem.I use the spring-security 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

In your spring web security config add the following lines

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

You can find the filter is here:
https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter

I use reactjs and you don't have to do anything on the UI side, it just works